# Scaning for bluetooth device with MIT App Inventor 2

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, app-inventor

I am trying to connect an arduino has bluetooh(HC-06) with an android phone. I found and applied below block but I can only connect to paired devices without scanning.

How can I scan for available bluetooth devices and connect them using MIT App Inventor 2? What should be the block for scan operation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation of the bluetooth component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#BluetoothClient)

As you can see, there is no block available to scan for devices, **you only can get a list of paired Bluetooth devices**....

> AddressesAndNames
>       The addresses and names of paired Bluetooth devices

However you can create your own extension and create your own blocks, for more information, [see the announcement here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ).

Btw... see the following screenshot for **how to connect correctly**
[image]

**EDIT: to scan for devices you can use the [classic bluetooth extension](https://puravidaapps.com/bluetooth.php).**
Note: I'm the author of that extension.

Comment: Im trying to connect an android to my macbook air and I get the mac list, select connect to it, but I get a android popup with Error 507: Unable to connect.  Is the device turned on?

Comment: @marciokoko Please do not hijack threads. If you have a question, please [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in a new thread.